# How can I set gvim's window width to 80 columns of text, plus the ones needed to show the line number

Tags: vim, gvim

I use gvim with

```
set number
```

in my `.vimrc` so it shows the linenumber, plus a space, before every line.

If the document has less than 10 lines, this takes 2 columns, If it has more than 10, 3 columns and so on.

If I put

```
set lines=40 columns=80
```

in `.gvimrc`, it will show 78 columns of code and 2 for the linenumber plus pace, or 77 + 3 and so on.

I'd like the window width to be set to 80 columns + whatever number of columns are necessary to show the linenumber.

It doesn't need to be dynamic, but I'd like to be able to read the number of lines of a given file and set `columns` according. (Of course, a dynamic solution would be really neat, but not essential)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
au BufRead * let &numberwidth = float2nr(log10(line("$"))) + 2
          \| let &columns = &numberwidth + 80
```

Every time you load a buffer (i.e., open a file), that will determine the number of columns required to show the largest line number, set the 'numberwidth' option accordingly, and set 'columns' to that number plus 80 for your text.

Comment: Thanks! It works great when opening a file.

Any idea how to make this happen when switching tabs too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vim's autocommand events are listed at `:help autocommand-events`. Among them is `TabEnter`, so you could try replacing `BufRead` by `BufRead,TabEnter` in the example above and see if that gives you the behavior you want. I have not tested the example with that event myself.

Comment: Thank you @garyjohn, TabEnter worked as expected.

Maybe later I will play with those autocommand-events. They are eally useful!

Comment: Can anyone cleverer than me augment this so it does the right thing if 'numbers' are not displayed (ie. zero width)? Presumably a vim ternary operator mixed in?

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks! How would you set a maximum numberwidth? For example if a file has very long lines, how could I limit it to a sensible amount?

Comment: @david_nash: `'numberwidth'` grows only logarithmically with the number of lines in the file, so if you can afford the horizontal space to have `'number'` enabled at all, I wouldn't think you'd have to worry about limiting it.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: It would be easy enough to control this with a ternary operator (`:help expr1`) or with an if/endif (e.g., `:help options-in-terminal`). The problem is changing &columns when `'number'` is changed. I thought of using the OptionSet autocommand event, but `:help OptionSet` says it's a bad idea to reset an option while processing this event.

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
set lines=24 columns=84
```

in my $HOME/.gvimrc which gives me what you want.  I rarely (if ever) have files that are longer the 999 lines so it works for me.

Comment: Thats what I was doing, but keeping exactly 80 columns of text is nice because I can prevent ending up with 81 chars in one line, which is no  big deal, but is nice to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

I set the numberwidth to, say, 5  and then set the columns to 85 (80+5)
That should be good for files from 0 lines to a million lines.

Here is what you may have to put in (default) ~/.vimrc file

```
set numberwidth=5  "Good for files upto a million lines
set columns=85
set nu
```

You will see line number are formatted with '%5d' (5 is the numberwidth above) instead of default '%d' format, wasting a bit of real-estate before the line numbers, but maintaining consistency.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please be aware you have posted an answer to a question that is very old. Although there is nothing wrong with doing so, just be aware you may not get a response.